# Running python script on anisble

Tags: python, ansible

I have an ansible server that I find works fine, but when I try to run a python script on the deployed servers I get `no such file or directory`, even though I visually confirm they are there.

Here's my anisble playbook code:

```
create a user directory and a dev subdirectory
- name: Create directory for python files
  file: path=/home/{{ user_name }}/python_files
    state=directory
    owner={{ user_name }}
    group={{ user_name }}
    mode=755

- name: Copy python file over
  copy: 
    src=example.py 
    dest=/home/{{ user_name }}/python_files/example.py
    owner={{ user_name }}
    group={{ user_name }}
    mode=777 

- name: Execute script
  command: /home/{{ user_name }}/python_files/example.py
```

---

This is the error I get:

```
TASK [python-dev : Execute script] *********************************************
task path: /usr/share/ansible-demo/roles/python-dev/tasks/main.yml:37
<192.168.1.240> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: None
<192.168.1.240> SSH: EXEC sshpass -d14 ssh -C -vvv -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/home/achilles/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r -tt 192.168.1.240 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'( umask 22 && mkdir -p "` echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1460496110.48-100414848375832 `" && echo "` echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1460496110.48-100414848375832 `" )'"'"''
<192.168.1.240> PUT /tmp/tmpcLPC60 TO /home/achilles/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1460496110.48-100414848375832/command
<192.168.1.240> SSH: EXEC sshpass -d14 sftp -b - -C -vvv -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/home/achilles/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r '[192.168.1.240]'
<192.168.1.240> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: None
<192.168.1.240> SSH: EXEC sshpass -d14 ssh -C -vvv -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/home/achilles/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r -tt 192.168.1.240 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'sudo -H -S  -p "[sudo via ansible, key=dbpmnfbipbkpualueeaxdbkosbjdwsdk] password: " -u root /bin/sh -c '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'echo BECOME-SUCCESS-dbpmnfbipbkpualueeaxdbkosbjdwsdk; /bin/sh -c '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'LANG=en_US.UTF-8 LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8 /usr/bin/python /home/achilles/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1460496110.48-100414848375832/command; rm -rf "/home/achilles/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1460496110.48-100414848375832/" > /dev/null 2>&1'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"''"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"''"'"''

fatal: [192.168.1.240]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "cmd": "/home/achilles/python_files/example.py", "failed": true, "invocation": {"module_args": {"_raw_params": "/home/achilles/python_files/example.py", "_uses_shell": false, "chdir": null, "creates": null, "executable": null, "removes": null, "warn": true}, "module_name": "command"}, "msg": "[Errno 2] No such file or directory", "rc": 2}
```

---

The directory permissions look ok on the deployed server:

```
achilles@ansible-test:~/python_files$ ll
total 12
drwxr-xr-x  2 achilles achilles 4096 Apr 12 15:56 ./
drwxr-xr-x 18 achilles achilles 4096 Apr 12 15:56 ../
-rwxrwxrwx  1 achilles achilles  153 Apr 12 15:56 example.py*
```

Any suggestions? I don't think I overlooked the obvious but I am fairly new to ansible and this [link](https://serverfault.com/questions/536908/ansible-playbook-to-upload-and-execute-a-python-script) didn't help.

Comment: What's the first line of example.py?

Comment: It looks like the first line has a cut and past error on it. So yeah thats the problem with that error

Answer (score 2):

In order to run a python script in another directory, you will need to implement a `chdir`. [Ansible](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/command_module.html) allows you to do this through their `args` parameter.

Example:

```
- name: Execute Script
  command: python example.py
  args:
    chdir: /home/{{user_name}}/python_files/
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use absolute paths and double check that the destination path exists in the remote servers.

Answer (score 0):

The error came from the fist line of the python code in the shebang. There was a cut and paste error.

Comment: What did it say? What should it say instead?