# Cannot execute sqlite statement with Ansible command module - [Errno 2] No such file or directory: b'sqlite3'"

Tags: ansible, ubuntu-18.04, sqlite

I am trying to run a simple query on many servers. I know 100% that the file and directory in question exist.

I can do simple commands, such as `ls`, `pwd`, `whoami`, etc, and I can run the `sqlite` command on the remote host itself.

The playbook task:

```
- name: Do a test SELECT statement
  become: yes
  become_user: root
  command: sqlite3 /usr/local/share/sqlite/dbfile.sqlite3 "SELECT * FROM db WHERE hostname="{{ db_server_prompt }}""
  register: query_result

- debug: var=query_result.stdout_lines
```

The error I'm receiving is  `"msg": "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: b'sqlite3'",`.

Is there something wrong with my syntax? Why is it telling me there's "`No such file or directory`" when using the sqlite3 command? I've tried the absolute path to the executable (`/usr/bin/sqlite3`), but I get the same error.

**Update** I tried to use `chdir` as an argument per [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/769898/running-python-script-on-anisble), but I get `Unable to change directory before execution`. I also tried the absolute path to `sqlite` with `/usr/bin/sqlite3`. None of these things are working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have a look into [Whats the difference between ansible `raw`, `shell` and `command`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57804071/) and try the following

```
- name: Do a test SELECT statement
  become: yes
  become_user: root
  shell:
    cmd: /usr/bin/sqlite3 /usr/local/share/sqlite/dbfile.sqlite3 "SELECT * FROM db WHERE hostname={{ db_server_prompt }}"
  register: query_result

- name: Show query result
  debug: 
    var: query_result.stdout_lines
```

Comment: I would've never thought to put `cmd` with the `shell` module. After adding some double quotes around the `SELECT` and single quotes around the `db_server_prompt` variable, it worked! I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue but with ifquery : `ifquery -l", "msg": "[Errno 2] No such file or directory`.

The thing is that `ifquery` needs root permissions, and I was running my playbook without requesting root permissions.

To run the playbook as root, simply use the `-b` option with `ansible-playbook`, or add `become=True` in your ansible.cfg.